# Is it possible to show steps of calculation in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say for example that I have these number in diffetent cells : 5 , 3 , 2. In different cell I type "=SUM(*cells of my numbers*)". So my question is : is it possible that result will be shown as *"5 + 3 + 2"* instead of just "*10*"?
BTW: I know that it's rather strange question.

Comment: you would need to create a VBA macro for that... so... yes?

Comment: `=A1&" + "&A2&" + "&A3` ?

Comment: Last comment worked for me, thank you very much!

Comment: appreciate if u can click on the tick to mark this question as 'answered'. tq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned via comment & assuming A1:A3 contain the desired value, the formula :

```
=A1&" + "&A2&" + "&A3
```

should do what you need. It is not a `strange question`. Maybe the (technically closer) `is it possible that cell to display..`  term is closer to what the technical communities here have in mind. (I'm not complaining.. english is hard on me too).

<sub>*Just fyi, "show calculation step" is the use of [ (select cell with formula) > Formula > Evaluate ] function in excel. It may be the reason this question is misunderstood. (^_^)\</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TEXTJOIN`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" + ",TRUE,A1:C1)&" = "&SUM(A1:C1)
```

[image: 2+3+5=10]